# How to limit the amount of bullets in a JavaScript Game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So the question is really bad because I don't know what to ask or call what I'm trying to do, but...

I have a game I'm creating and I've added in an array for the lasers. It works fine but I want to limit the number of lasers that can be on the screen at once so the player doesn't just spam the space bar to win.

I tried limiting it by making a set number of bullets which only allows the user to shoot twice but where I tried to add back bullets once it reached the top of the canvas so they could start shooting again but it didn't work.

I assume this is because it is within the spacePressed if and so it considers spacePressed to be false so it won't run where it adds one bullet but when I put the adding bullets if outside the spacePressed it still didn't work.

I'm not sure how to go about doing what I'm trying to do and would appreciate any ideas towards fixing this. I will also have to add in later where the laser disappears upon hitting the meteor and adds back one bullet so I would also like help with figuring that out.

https://jsfiddle.net/200uaqrn/18/ <-before adding any bullets

https://jsfiddle.net/200uaqrn/19/ <-adding in my attempt to create limited bullets

```
if(spacePressed) {
  if(lasers.y<=laserSize) {
    bullets+=1;
  }
  else{
    drawLaser();
    lasers.forEach(function(laser,index){
      laser.y-=laserdY;
    })
  }
}
```

Also separate question for the same project I'm going to later make multiple meteors falling at once and I assume I would use an array for that. But I don't know how to use that array to make them fall from random y cords at different times, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the laser, you can try to just set a function with timeout:

```
var canFire = true;

function allowFire() {
    canFire = true;
}

function newLaser() {
    this.x = turretX
    this.y = canvas.height - 75
    canFire = false;
    setTimeout(allowFire, 3000);
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        rightPressed = true;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 32 && canFire == true) {
        spacePressed = true;
        lasers.push(new newLaser())
    }
}
```

*Note that 3000 is the cooldown there.*

This will limit the amount of bullets **at the same time** in the screen, as the player will only shoot every x milliseconds, if you wanna a exact amount of bullets, you can do a `var` for them with the desired amount, then remove one every time that the player press space, and do a check for `> 0` here: `(e.keyCode === 32 && canFire == true)`

For the meteors if you're going to use the array, to make them fall random you can use this function(found in [Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)):

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

So you can use it for the coordinates and for the time you can use a timeout(like above) with a random time too, using this(from the same source):

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

If it's a array you can use it like `getRandomArbitrary(i * 1000, i * 3000)` as `i` being the index in a `for` loop. It depends on how specifically you wanna them to work, there's many ways to do that, a function that call itself, while loop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"It works fine but I want to limit the number of lasers that can be on the screen at once so the player doesn't just spam the space bar to win."

So it sounds like what you want to do is not limit the amount of bullets, but limit the ability of the player to shoot. You could ensure that some time (a tenth of a second?) must pass before the player can shoot again.

As for random numbers, see the later examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) on how to get random numbers in some range.